# Typegoose is not saving array subdocuments properly in Nest.js app

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, typegoose

I'm attempting to save an array of `TaskOutcome` subdocuments in my `Task` model, following the [typegoose documentation](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/api/decorators/prop/#array-options):

```js
import { prop } from '@typegoose/typegoose';

class TaskOutcome {
   @prop({ required: true }) public inputId: string;
   @prop() public label?: string;
   @prop() public value?: string;
}

export class Task {
   @prop() public _id: string;
   ...
   @prop({ _id: false, type: () => [TaskOutcome] })
   public outcomes: TaskOutcome[];
}
```

```js
@Injectable()
export class TaskService {

   constructor(
      @InjectModel(Task) private readonly model: ReturnModelType<typeof Task>,
   ) {}

   public async saveTask(data: TaskDTO) {
      console.log(data.outcomes);
      const options: QueryOptions = { upsert: true, new: true };
      const result = await this.model.findByIdAndUpdate(data.id, data, options);
      console.log(result.outcomes);
   }
}
```

When I save a task document, all its props are saved as expected, except the `outcomes` array subdocuments. Instead, all I get is an array of empty objects. So even though the first `console.log` above shows me the correct input data, the second `console.log` gives me `[{},{},{}]` (confirmed when inspecting the database).

Anything obvious I'm doing wrong?

I'm using `@nestjs/core@8.2.4`, `@typegoose/typegoose@9.3.1`, `nestjs-typegoose@7.1.38`, and `mongoose@6.1.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrggghh. Ignore me. The code above is working perfectly fine.

Instead there seems to be a bug with the Nest.js `ValidationPipe`, which was very subtly mangling my incoming TaskDTO data - so my `outcomes` array looked fine at a glance in the console, but was actually an **array of arrays**, instead of an **array of objects**.

So typegoose was rightly ignoring it. If anyone stumbles on to this question, **check the data you are saving really is exactly what it should be**